# Sequentially group / process contents with XSLT 2.0 / XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

**Meta**

- XSLT 2.0
- XSL-FO

I have to do two things:

1.) I want to apply templates for certain nodes (p) that do not follow after a (x).

So for the following example the only node that should be processed should be **the first (p)**.

**XML**

```
<p>example...</p>
<x>example...</x>
<p>example...</p>
<p>example...</p>
<p>example...</p>
<x>example...</x>
<p>example...</p>
<p>example...</p>
```

2.) I also want to process the contents for all (p) nodes as groups that follow after each (x).

So for the example above the contents that follow after each x should be put into the block element (s. below).

```
<xsl:template match="x">
    <fo:block>
        <!-- content from following (p) nodes until the next following (x) -->
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a simple way to do this with groups or intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown any parent element but write a template for that parent:

```
<xsl:template match="div[x]">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="x">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::x">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample is at http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQeW.

Comment: What I´m trying to achieve is to simply apply all contents from <p> that is not a following sibling of <x> AND to apply the contents of <p> after each <x> inside of a template for <x> (and that for each group <p> starting with <x>).

Comment: So you insist on doing the coding in a template for `x` elements? It sounds to me as if doing it in a template matching the parent elements of those `x` and `p` elements is the better approach. If you want to do it in a template for `x` elements then use sibling recursion. But that is an approach necessary in XSLT 1.0, in 2.0 you have `for-each-group group-starting-with`.

Comment: Could you give an example for grouping all elements after each x and additionally apply all contents for p elements that are not following siblings of x?

Comment: I have posted an answer, so far I don't understand why you don't use that. If you want to use XSLT 1.0 techniques like sibling recursion then do e.g. `<xsl:template match="x"><fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::p]" mode="group"/></fo:block></xsl:template><xsl:template match="p" mode="group"><xsl:copy-of select="."/><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::p]" mode="group"/></xsl:template>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing the same thing for all groups of `p` and you really don't care about the `x` elements, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="self::p">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

but if you really did want to do something different for the first `p` (or multiple first `p`):

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="self::p">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[empty(preceding-sibling::x)]">
  <fo:block font-family="serif">
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

since `current-group()` still works in other templates while you're within an iteration of the `xsl:for-each-group`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you I found a working solution.

I created a template for the parent container element (s. below):

```
<xsl:template match="container">
    <xsl:for-each group select="*" group-starting-with="x">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::x">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() = 1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

And additionally a template for the x element (s.below):

```
<xsl:template match="x">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

Contents are processed in groups if preceding sibling is x; and also regulary if not but not as part of any x group.

*These things are quiet hard to describe - Thank you for your patience!*

Comment: You could replace `current-group()[position() = 1]` with `.`.  From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group: "Within the sequence constructor, the context item is the initial item of the relevant group".